How would I smoothly swivel a unity 3D camera around an object at a given distance to look at the object in the direction of the velocity
I’m familiar with Cinemachine, but I haven't found anything that accomplishes what I'm trying to do. I'm working on a car game, although the specific game concept isn't relevant to the problem. Right now, I'm building a framework for the camera to smoothly swivel around the player based on the car’s flat velocity (ignoring any Y-axis velocity). For example, If the car is moving forward and the camera isn't already positioned behind it at a specified distance, the camera should smoothly swivel along the shortest path to reach that position.
I have fixed the function to receive the proper transform position relative to the car it is following
here is the new function:
public Vector3 GetFollowOffsetPosition(Vector3 followerPosition, Vector3 followObjectPosition, Vector3 followObjectVelocity, float followDistance)
{
    // If the followed object is stationary, just return the current position (no offset).
    Vector3 noYVelocity = new Vector3(followObjectVelocity.x, 0f, followObjectVelocity.z);
    if (noYVelocity.magnitude < minSpeedThreshold)
    {
        return defaultCamPosition; // No significant velocity, return current follower position.
    }

    // Get the direction of the followed object's velocity (ignoring y component for horizontal following).
    Vector3 velocityDirection = noYVelocity.normalized;

    // Calculate the offset position: followObject's position minus the offset along the velocity direction.
    Vector3 offsetPosition = new Vector3(-Mathf.Sign(velocityDirection.z) * velocityDirection.x, 0f, velocityDirection.z) * followDistance;


    offsetPosition.y = defaultCamPosition.y;

    // Return the calculated offset position.
    return offsetPosition;
}

The camera does not swivel smoothly around the car now it is just very jumpy.  The get follow angle gets the angle difference between the target position and the current position from the follow object. The swivel function is supposed to use this to swivel around from the current position to the target position.  but it gets very jittery and does not maintain the distance set out by the target position it is just supposed to smoothly swivel around the car from the current position to the target position in an elliptical path.
private Vector3 swivelCamera(Vector3 currentPos, Vector3 targetPosition, float rotationAngle, float semiMajorAxis, float semiMinorAxis)
{
//Vector3 direction = new Vector3(currentPos.x - targetPosition.x, 0f, Mathf.Abs(currentPos.z) - Mathf.Abs(targetPosition.z));
Vector3 direction = new Vector3(currentPos.x - targetPosition.x, 0f, currentPos.z - targetPosition.z);
    if (direction.magnitude < Mathf.Epsilon)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Direction vector is too small, cannot normalize!");
        return currentPos; // Return the current position if there's no valid direction
    }

    // Normalize the direction (unit length)
    direction = direction.normalized;



    // Ensure the sign of the original direction is maintained while scaling
    direction.x *= semiMinorAxis;  // Use the absolute value of the semiMinorAxis (side-to-side)
    direction.z *= semiMajorAxis;  // Use the absolute value of the semiMajorAxis (forward-backward)

    Debug.Log(direction.z);
    

    
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, rotationAngle, 0);  // Rotate by the specified angle around Y-axis
    Vector3 rotatedDirection = rotation * direction;

    // Step 5: Calculate the new camera position by adding the rotated direction to the target position
    Vector3 newPosition = targetPosition + rotatedDirection;

    // Step 6: Return the new position of the camera
    return newPosition;
}



private float GetSwivelAngleDifference(Vector3 currentSwivelPos, Vector3 targetSwivelPos, Vector3 followObjectPos)
{
    Vector3 currentSwivelVector = currentSwivelPos - followObjectPos;
    Vector3 targetSwivelVector = targetSwivelPos - followObjectPos;

    currentSwivelVector.y = 0;
    targetSwivelVector.y = 0;

    if (currentSwivelVector.magnitude < Mathf.Epsilon || targetSwivelVector.magnitude < Mathf.Epsilon)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Swivel vectors are too small to normalize.");
        return 0f;
    }

    currentSwivelVector.Normalize();
    targetSwivelVector.Normalize();

    // Standard dot product calculation (no need for z-axis check).
    float dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(currentSwivelVector, targetSwivelVector);

    dotProduct = Mathf.Clamp(dotProduct, -1f, 1f);

    float angle = Mathf.Acos(dotProduct) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    // Cross product to determine the sign of the angle.
    Vector3 crossProduct = Vector3.Cross(currentSwivelVector, targetSwivelVector);
    if (crossProduct.y < 0)
    {
        angle = -angle;
    }

    return angle;
}


Could you just place a transform where the camera should end up (placing the forward axis in direction of the car), and then (s)lerp the camera's transform towards the target transform based on the velocity?
